# jQuery/css Keep divs bottom

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-animate

So I have container and inside there is yui library with 5 divs. This divs are menus. So what i want to do is that when I move mouse over div only this one will animate UP and when I move mouse somewhere else it will animate DOWN. Now my divs animate each for themseleves on hover. But problem is that when one animate up others also do, like on this img: http://prntscr.com/2i6p9i.  So what should I do to kepp other down like Gallery...

Structure of html and js is on this topic, for some resones i cound not put code in here.
[jQuery "animating" multiple divs inisde div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052164/jquery-animating-multiple-divs-inisde-div)